# How to specify type of class method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to specify the type of a class method using a type that I've already defined elsewhere?

```
type AnimalFunctions = {
  roar(word: string): Promise<void>;
  eat(): Promise<boolean>;
};

export class Animal {
  constructor()
  async myRoar(param) {
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use AnimalFunctions["roar"] as the type for the myRoar function, so that it types both the params as well as the return type. I'm kind of blanking on what the syntax should be.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-breeze-i6m12m?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Is there an alternative? I'm also using a decorator in this situation above the myRoar function, and getting 

The return type of a property decorator function must be either 'void' or 'any'.
  Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(1236)